# How to deploy .bna file on Hyperledger Fabric on Multiple Hosts

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have followed the tutorial for Hyperledger Fabric on Multiple Hosts
by Wahab https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f.
Now, I am trying to deploy my own .bna file instead of chaincode. can anybody help how to deploy that. I am unable to install the card.
Connection.json

```js
{
    "name": "fabric-network",
    "x-type": "hlfv1",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://localhost:7051",
            "eventUrl": "grpc://localhost:7053"
        },
        "peer1.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://192.168.64.82:7051",
            "eventUrl": "grpc://192.168.64.82:7053"
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.example.com": {
            "url": "http://localhost:7054",
            "caName": "ca.example.com"
        }
    },
    "orderers": {
        "orderer.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://localhost:7050"
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org1": {
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.org1.example.com",
                "peer1.org1.example.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.example.com"
            ]
        }
    },
    "channels": {
        "mychannel": {
            "orderers": [
                "orderer.example.com"
            ],
            "peers": {
                "peer0.org1.example.com": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                },
                "peer1.org1.example.com": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                 }
               
            }
        }
    },
    "client": {
        "organization": "Org1",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300",
                    "eventHub": "300",
                    "eventReg": "300"
                },
                "orderer": "300"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to follow the [official tutorial of Hyperledger Composer](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org).

It is also explained how to configure the connection profile for the cards.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on the same issue, used the same tutorial. Well I have managed to configure connection profile so that it connects, but got other problems with authorization and stuff.

I think your ports aren't right try these (that worked for me):

```
 "peer0.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://localhost:8051",
        "eventUrl": "grpc://localhost:8053"
    },
    "peer1.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://192.168.64.82:9051",
        "eventUrl": "grpc://192.168.64.82:9053"
```